# Loop through all the user controls on a page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Want to loop through all the user controls that exist on the page and get their IDs. How do I do it?

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF or ASP.NET? I suspect the latter, but you never know.

Comment: By "user controls" do you mean *managed controls* or specifically user controls (.ascx)?

Comment: @ChrisF: You guess it right! ASP.Net it is
@CAbbott: .ascx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get each User Control, you'd have to test the Type of the control:

**EDIT:** I modified my example to go through all controls recursively:

**Method**

```
public void GetUserControls(ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach (Control ctl in controls)
    {
        if (ctl is UserControl)
        {
            // Do whatever.
        }

        if (ctl.Controls.Count > 0)
            GetUserControls(ctl.Controls);
    }
}
```

**Called**

```
GetUserControls(Page.Controls);
```

Comment: if (curControl is UserControl) is never true. And I do have a usercontrol on the page

Comment: I've tested this on a page where I have a user control and it finds it.  Are you deriving your control from `System.Web.UI.UserControl`?

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
var listOfUserControls = GetUserControls(Page);

...

public List<UserControl> GetUserControls(Control ctrl)
{
  var uCtrls = new List<UserControl>();
  foreach (Control child in ctrl.Controls) {
    if (child is UserControl) uCtrls.Add((UserControl)child);
    uCtrls.AddRange(GetUserControls(child);
  }

  return uCtrls;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(Control control: Page.Controls)
{

    //do something with control object

}
```

Comment: But then, it loops through all controls. How can a user control be differentiated. GetType()??

Comment: Controls can be nested so you need a recursive function to loop through all controls.

Answer (score 2):

I created an extension method to do this, which works really nicely with LINQ.

```
<Extension()>
Public Function DecendentControls(ParentControl As Control) As Control()
    Dim controls As New List(Of Control)

    For Each myControl As Control In ParentControl.Controls
        controls.Add(myControl)
        controls.AddRange(myControl.DecendentControls)
    Next

    Return controls.ToArray
End Function
```

Then with LINQ you can do something like this to set all the checkboxes on a page to unchecked:

```
For Each myControl As CheckBox In pnlMain.DecendentControls.Where(Function(x) TypeOf x Is CheckBox)
    myControl.Checked = False
Next
```