# Retrieve value of dynamic radio button controls in asp:table

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, findcontrol

I am creating radio button dynamically inside asp:table. iI want to get the id of the selected radio button.

1. How to check the control type
2. How to get its ID.

   ```
       RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
       radioButton.ID = id + "RadioButton";
       radioButton.ToolTip = text;
       radioButton.Attributes.Add("id", id);
       radioButton.GroupName = categoryID + "Questions";
       radioButton.EnableViewState = true;
       radioButton.AutoPostBack = true;
       radioButton.Checked = isSelected;
       radioButton.CssClass = style;

       TableCell cell = new TableCell();
       cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
       cell.Controls.Add(radioButton);
       TableRow row = new TableRow();
       row.Cells.Add(cell);
       table.Rows.Add(row);
   ```

Comment: You want to get id whilst postback on server side?

Comment: See this SO post: [Getting a lits of all child controls of a control, by type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7555309/485076)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution. i am posting this solution to help others.

```
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();            
        foreach (TableRow tr in QuestionTable.Controls)
        {
            foreach (TableCell tc in tr.Controls)
            {
                if (tc.Controls[0] is RadioButton)
                {
                    rb = (RadioButton)tc.Controls[0];
                    if (rb.Checked)
                    {
                        string aa = rb.ID;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }               
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use jQuery.

Specify a class for thr radio button

Loop through the class using 'each' function

Then in 'each' function, check whether (this) object is decorated with 'selected' or 'checked' property.