# How to get Label text from a list of controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

I want to loop through all the controls in an ASP.Net `DetailsView` and get all the `Labels` in a List. Then I want to do something to the text of each `Label`. I'm using the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555209/getting-a-lits-of-all-child-controls-of-a-control-by-type) as a guide. It works fine, but I can't access the `Text` property of the `Labels` because I'm creating a List of `Controls` and `Controls` don't have a `Text` property. Here's my code:

```
List<Control> ControlsToCheck = GetAllLabelControls(dvPurchaseOrder).ToList();
foreach (Control c in ControlsToCheck)
{
    c.Text = HighlightSearchTerms(c.Text, Request.QueryString["searchstring"]);
}

public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllLabelControls(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (control is Label)
            yield return control;
        foreach (Control descendant in GetAllLabelControls(control))
        {
            if (descendant is Label)
                yield return descendant;
        }
    }
}
```

In the debugger, I can see the `Text` of each `Control`, but my line

```
c.Text = HighlightSearchTerms(c.Text, Request.QueryString["searchstring"]);
```

won't compile:

> System.Web.UI.Control does not contain a definition for Text and no
>   extension method accepting a first argument of type
>   System.Web.UI.Control could be found.

BTW, if I use the exact syntax suggested in the link I reference above,

```
List<Control> ControlsToCheck = GetAllControls(dv).OfType<Label>().ToList();
```

I get an error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   System.Collections.Generic.List to
>   System.Collections.Generic.List

How can I get the `Text` of the `Labels`?

---

The modified code, which works as per @S.Akbari's answer is to replace

```
List<Control> ControlsToCheck = GetAllLabelControls(dvPurchaseOrder).ToList();
foreach (Control c in ControlsToCheck)
```

with

```
foreach (Label lbl in GetAllLabelControls(dvPurchaseOrder).OfType<Label>().Cast<Label>())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (Label lbl in dvPurchaseOrder.Controls.OfType<Label>().Cast<Label>())
{
    lbl.Text = "";//Or other properties of the Label
}
```

Comment: That did it! I've added my new code to my question above. Thanks so much!