# how to make a function that calculates how many checkboxes is checked inside a groupbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                count++;
            }
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                count++;
            }
            if (checkBox3.Checked)
            {
                count++;
            }
            if (checkBox4.Checked)
            {
                count++;
            }
            if (checkBox5.Checked)
            {
                count++;
            }
            MessageBox.Show($"{count}");
```

Comment: 1. Write a function.  2. Inside that function, check a checkbox's state. If its checked, increment a counter.  3. Repeat for each checkbox.  4. You have your result

Comment: Maybe if you include some of your code, and a good-faith attempt at this, then we would be happy to help further.

Comment: @Amy excuse me i'm not used to Stackoverflow yet hahaha I edited and posted part of my code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295242/get-the-list-of-child-controls-inside-a-groupbox Use this as a starting point. You don't need all the levels that they have, but the concept is exactly the same.

Comment: You want to start from 0 when you count, here you're counting how many times checks were done.

Comment: @Soleil yes count is a global var and initiated as zero

Comment: @MohammedAbdeen it is not visible here in your code. You need to add this in your post. Furthermore the initialization should be in the function, or you open the path ot spaghetti code.

Answer (score 2):

This is a one-liner:

```
MessageBox.Show(MyGroupBox.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Count(b => b.Checked));
```

Comment: `MessageBox` is not helping; you rather want a property (int) or an equivalent function.

Comment: @Soleil I used MessageBox to mimic the code at the end of the question

Comment: It makes sense, however inlining everything is not a good practice, you still want a property and use it in the MessageBox. Furthermore, when is it computed ? When any Checked property is changed ? at request ?

Comment: @Soleil When `button3_Click` is called, as per the question?